# VS2015 open/import cordova project

Tags: cordova, import, visual-studio-2015

I need to import loaded Cordova project to VS2015 with Cordova Tools. Simply loading files to www folder, and replacing config.xml dont work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

1. create new Project in vs2015
2. build the Project to make sure there is no problem with your vs2015 installation.
3. copy content from old index.html to new index.html
4. copy everything related, e.g. images, html files (if you are not using SPA), js files, css files, under the www directory, but do not copy any api.
5. open config.xml in vs2015 by double click(do not use view code to open), add all related api.
6. build the Project again.

it should work now unless some Api are not compatible with vs2015.